# Scripted trajectorie lagging when Gazebo started with launchfile

Tags: gazebo, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am not sure if this belongs to the ROS Forum or to the Gazebo Forum. I created a world with an actor which is executing a trajectory. When I open the world with "gazebo world" the trajectory is executed as intended. But when I start gazebo with "roslaunch launchfile" the trajectory is lagging heavily. It does not move for several seconds and sometimes execute the animation normaly. The Sim shows stable fps.

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 on x86 with all latest updates, ROS Melodic and Gazebo 9.

My world:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<sdf version="1.6">
  <world name="default">
     <include>
        <uri>model://ground_plane</uri>
     </include>
     <include>
        <uri>model://sun</uri>
     </include>
     <actor name="animated_box">
     <link name="box_link">
        <visual name="visual">
           <geometry>
           <box>
              <size>.2 .2 .2</size>
           </box>
           </geometry>
        </visual>
     </link>
     <script>
        <loop>true</loop>
        <auto_start>true</auto_start>
        <trajectory id="0" type="square">
           <waypoint>
              <time>0.0</time>
              <pose>-1 -1 .11 0 0 0</pose>
           </waypoint>
           <waypoint>
              <time>2.0</time>
              <pose>-1 1 .11 0 0 0</pose>
           </waypoint>
           <waypoint>
              <time>4.0</time>
              <pose>-1 -1 .11 0 0 0</pose>
           </waypoint>
        </trajectory>
     </script>
     </actor>
  </world>
```

My Launchfile:

```
    <launch>
    <arg name="model" default="burger" doc="model type [burger, waffle, waffle_pi]"/>

    <arg name="world" value="$(find pathfinder)/worlds/animated.world"/>
    <arg name="x_pos" default="-3.0"/>
    <arg name="y_pos" default="1.0"/>
    <arg name="z_pos" default="0.0"/>
    <include file="$(find gazebo_ros)/launch/empty_world.launch">
        <arg name="world_name" value="$(arg world)"/>
        <arg name="paused" value="false"/>
        <arg name="use_sim_time" value="true"/>
        <arg name="gui" value="true"/>
        <arg name="headless" value="false"/>
        <arg name="debug" value="false"/>
        <arg name="verbose" value="false" />
    </include>

    <param name="robot_description" command="$(find xacro)/xacro --inorder $(find turtlebot3_description)/urdf/turtlebot3_$(arg model).urdf.xacro" />
    <node pkg="gazebo_ros" type="spawn_model" name="spawn_urdf"  args="-urdf -model turtlebot3_$(arg model) -x $(arg x_pos) -y $(arg y_pos) -z $(arg z_pos) -param robot_description" />  
</launch>
```

Output from roslaunch:

```
    ... logging to /home/user/.ros/log/93683bcc-fcea-11ea-848c-1831bf51188e/roslaunch-UsersPC-25520.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take a while.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.
]2;/home/user/catkin_ws/src/pathfinder/launch/pathfinder_animated.launch
[1mstarted roslaunch server http://UsersPC:40911/[0m

SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
* /gazebo/enable_ros_network: True
* /robot_description: <?xml version="1....
* /rosdistro: melodic
* /rosversion: 1.14.9
* /use_sim_time: True

NODES
  /
    gazebo (gazebo_ros/gzserver)
    gazebo_gui (gazebo_ros/gzclient)
    spawn_urdf (gazebo_ros/spawn_model)

[1mROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311[0m
]2;/home/user/catkin_ws/src/pathfinder/launch/pathfinder_animated.launch http://localhost:11311
[1mprocess[gazebo-1]: started with pid [25542][0m
[1mprocess[gazebo_gui-2]: started with pid [25547][0m
[1mprocess[spawn_urdf-3]: started with pid [25552][0m
[1m[spawn_urdf-3] process has finished cleanly
log file: /home/user/.ros/log/93683bcc-fcea-11ea-848c-1831bf51188e/spawn_urdf-3*.log[0m
[gazebo_gui-2] killing on exit
[gazebo-1] killing on exit
shutting down processing monitor...
... shutting down processing monitor complete
[1mdone[0m
```

Thats how it looks with "gazebo world":
[image: image description]
and thats how it looks with "roslaunch launchfile":
[image: image description]
(Visual bugs are from recording)

Thanks in advance!
Tavaro

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/362088/scripted-trajectorie-lagging-when-gazebo-started-with-launchfile/) by [Tavaro](https://answers.ros.org/users/59909/tavaro/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2020-09-22

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [wojciechu](https://answers.ros.org/users/69278/wojciechu/) on 2021-02-03**:
Hi, I have identical problem. Did you solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I did solve it by not using the gazebo animation method. I switch to this method: https://github.com/modulabs/gazebo-tutorial/tree/master/1_build_robot/animatedbox

---

Originally posted by [Tavaro](https://answers.ros.org/users/59909/tavaro/) with karma: 16 on 2021-02-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0